# How to explain this problem in terms of inclusion exclusion?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, inclusion-exclusion

```
LAST WEEK'S TOTAL HOURS WORKED
AND HOURLY WAGES FOR
THE CASHIERS AT MARKET X

Cashier Hourly Wage | Worked Total Hours
P $4.25             | 40
Q $4.75             | 32
R $5.00             | 26
S $5.50             | 25
T $5.50             | 22

Note: Last week no more than two cashiers worked
at any one time, no cashier worked more than
12 hours on the same day, and on each day each
cashier worked continuously.
```

> If Market $X$ is open $96$ hours a week, how many hours was one cashier working alone and two cashiers working simultaneously?

I thought about the minimum and maximum bounds a person must work alone, must work together.

The number of days any given person works is Total hours divided by twelve.
You could brute force rearrange and count all the ways you could schedule them.

Do you start pairing the person who works the least number of total hours with the most to create all possible work schedules?

Wage is irrelevant.

If everyone worked more hours, you could have a maximum of $92 \cdot 2$ total hours worked.

$92/7=13.5$

[image]

Comment: You tried some complex approach,  ; it is much more simple. Total worked hours is 40+32+26+... ... ; then when you have this number, you should be able to conclude.  Many informations are not useful at this step.

Comment: Lourran is right. The only information you need to solve this is total hours worked, total hours open, and at any time either 1 cashier or 2 cashiers were working - never $0$ and never more than $2$.